# Creating private intance of excel for app

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I am making an app using Excel, with all user interaction happening in userforms.   I would like my app to run in a separate instance of excel than any other file already opened, or any file opened manualy by the user while my app runs. I found the folowing link to be relevant and interesting but I am not sure how to implement this in my application: [Answers.microsoft.com Can I create an instance of Excel that can only be accessed by my VBA project?](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_other-msoffice_custom/can-i-create-an-instance-of-excel-that-can-only-be/98d1ef9d-76aa-43cf-bf7b-6324fcb19018)

Here is how I would like to implement it:

I use two files: StartFile.xlsb, SystemFile.xlsb

1. The user opens StartFile normaly by clicking on the file
2. Sheet1 of StartFile displays a warning if macros are not enabled.
3. Once macros are enabled, StartFile checks excel version etc...
4. If all is good StartFile then opens SystemFile in a new instance of excel, and closes itself
5. SystemFile opens and somehow makes its excel instance private (Using "Application.IgnoreRemoteRequests = True" ?)

Clarification: The user will not be able to interact with the private excel instance application at all. Its .visible setting will remain false. It is used to display userforms, so to the user this will look like a standalone app

Sidenote: How do I make sure my new instance of excel has macros enabled no matter the macro security settings? (the user has already enabled macros once) (I have not noticed this happening so far, could it?)

Comment: I would suggest you consider using some technology not hobbled by macro restrictions. HTA with JScript/VBScript (VBScript has the most similarity to VBA), or WinForms with C#/VB.NET (the WinForms model is similar to the VBA UserForms model) are the first possibilities that spring to mind.

Comment: You can't make sure that macros are enabled, and you can't change the setting of that restriction. Many corporations (and intelligent users) intentionally disable macros globally, and your app cannot force them to change. This is the drawback to depending on an entirely different application than yours to implement your major functionality. If you want to be able to control what your app can and can't do, write your own code.

Answer (score -2):

Is it something like this you are looking for?

You cannot change the macro security settings as that would undermine the whole purpose of having these settings. Alternative, you can properly search for a VBA module to changing the Windows registry for this.

Furthermore, be careful if you use `IgnoreRemoteRequests`then you have to reset it again everytime.

** Edited ** Hide the SystemFile workbook and just show the userform? And then close the SystemFile workbook when the userform is closed.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Application.Visible = False
UserForm1.Show
End Sub

'UserForm module
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Unload UserForm1
Application.Quit
End Sub
```

Comment: Went too fast, admitted. Updated the answer.

Comment: Still not it. Read it again. :-)

Comment: He wants to open SystemFile from his existing workbook. When that workbook is open, he wants to close the existing workbook so that SystemFile is the only one open. In SystemFile he has a UserForm that should be visible for the user, however, the workbook should not. I do not see why you need to open it in a "private" instance, when you can just hide the workbook and show the userform, meaning that the user cannot interact with the workbook anyway.

Comment: `IgnoreRemoteRequests`you can just use it to

Comment: .. to stop opening from explorer (but not from excel). But you just need to reset it before closing the workbook as it will be carrying on.

Comment: Whether you see a reason for it or not, the question asks about creating a private instance of Excel. Your answer does not show how to create a private instance of Excel; nor does it explain any valid reason why such a thing is not possible. Therefore, your post does not answer the question asked.

Comment: However, it is creating an alternative solution to his question. As you might know, things in VBA can be solved in many different ways.

Comment: Thank you both. @Niclas, the private instance of Excel is to prevent the user interfering by opening or closing other files while my userform is showing. I have found that if systemfile is not visible, with the userform visible, and the user opens and then closes a workbook in the same instance, the application closes. Apparently excel wants a least one visible workbook  to keep the application open.

Comment: As for the starterfile - system file strategy, it prevents the user from accessing the main app file directly. If they delete it nothing is lost. And as for the application security settings: obviously you cannot change them. But so far I have found that once the user enables macros in starterfile, they will not be prompted again for system file. I will leave this question unanswered for now, I have been using .ignoreremoterequests but have had issues and am open to new suggestions.